# Unity shader - syntax error

Tags: shader

I try to do a shader but I have some syntax errors. I don't understand.
the syntax errors come from lines:

```
void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOuput o)
```

---

```
float3 projNormal = saturate(pow(IN.worldNormal * 1.4, 4));
```

---

```
if (IN.worldNormal > 0)
```

---

The code is:

```
    shader "Triplanar" {
    Properties {
        _Side("Side",2D) = "white"{}
        _Top("Top",2D) = "white"{}
        _Bottom("Bottom",2D) = "white"{}
        _SideScale("Side Scale",float) = 2
        _TopScale("Top Scale",float) = 2
        _BottomScale("Bottom Scale",float) = 2
    }
        SubShader{
            Tags {
                "queue"="Geometry"
                "IgnoreProjector"="False"
                "RenderType"="Opaque"
            }
            Cull Back

                ZWrite on

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma surface surf Lambert
                #pragma exlude_renderers flash

                sampler2D _Side, _Top, _Bottom;
                float _SideScale, _TopScale, _BottomScale;

        struct Input {
            float3 worldPos;
            float3 worldNormal;
        };

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOuput o) 
        {
            float3 projNormal = saturate(pow(IN.worldNormal * 1.4, 4));

            //side x
            float3 x = tex2D(_Side, frac(IN.worldPos.zy * _SideScale)) * abs(IN.worldNormal.x);

            //top and bottom
            float3 y = 0;
            if (IN.worldNormal > 0)
            {
                y = tex2D(_Top, frac(IN.worldPos.zx * _TopScale)) * abs(IN.worldNormal.y);
            }
            else
            {
                y = tex2D(_Bottom, frac(IN.worldPos.zs * _BottomScale)) * abs(IN.worldNormal.y);
            }

            // side z

            float3 z tex2D(_Side, frac(IN.worldPos.xy * _SideScale)) * abs(IN.worldNormal.z);

            o.Albedo = z;
            o.Albedo = lerp(o.Albedo, x, projNormal.x)
            o.Albedo = lerp(o.Albedo, y, projNormal.y)


        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: unity tell me syntax error.  but I don't see where I missed on open brackets.

Comment: Syntax error at line 32 (on ) Syntax error at line 34 (on ) Syntax error at line 41 (on )

Comment: ohhh.. now i get it. I'll update your q. any decription for the errors?

Comment: anything the compiler is throwing at you could be useful.

Comment: he tells me only what I wrote before.

Comment: try to put curly brackets after parentheses, not on a new line